# install modules with custom module

Tags: 7

Is there any way to install all modules a in specific folder with a custom module? I need to install my custom module and have all modules in a specific folder installed automatically.

Comment: Define dependencies/required module on your module's info file is better practice

Answer (score 2):

If you define the modules in the subdirectory as dependencies of your main module, then they'll be enabled once your "controller" module is.

i.e.

```
name = Really Neat Widget
description = Provides a really neat widget for your site's sidebar.
core = 7.x
package = Views
dependencies[] = MODULE_ONE
dependencies[] = MODULE_TWO
```

[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202)

Alternatively, you could take a look at the [Master](https://www.drupal.org/project/master) module.

Answer (score 2):

If the modules you need to install are in a well know list, you can just add them as dependencies of your module. They will not get automatically installed, if Drush is not used to enable your custom module, but your custom module could be installed only if the administrator user installs and enables the dependencies.

If you need to programmatically install modules found in a folder, and you don't want to make assumptions about which modules are (maybe you don't control which modules are in that folder), you need to use [`file_scan_directory()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7) and [`module_enable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7). With the latter function:

- You don't need to check the modules are already enabled, since the function does it

  ```
  foreach ($module_list as $module) {
    // Only process modules that are not already enabled.
    $existing = db_query("SELECT status FROM {system} WHERE type = :type AND name = :name", array(
      ':type' => 'module',
      ':name' => $module,
    ))->fetchObject();
    if ($existing->status == 0) {
      // Load the module's code.
      drupal_load('module', $module);
      module_load_install($module);

      // ...
    }

    // ...
  }
  ```
- You don't need to invoke `hook_install()`

  ```
  // Now install the module if necessary.
  if (drupal_get_installed_schema_version($module, TRUE) == SCHEMA_UNINSTALLED) {
    drupal_install_schema($module);

    // Set the schema version to the number of the last update provided
    // by the module.
    $versions = drupal_get_schema_versions($module);
    $version = $versions ? max($versions) : SCHEMA_INSTALLED;

    // If the module has no current updates, but has some that were
    // previously removed, set the version to the value of
    // hook_update_last_removed().
    if ($last_removed = module_invoke($module, 'update_last_removed')) {
      $version = max($version, $last_removed);
    }
    drupal_set_installed_schema_version($module, $version);
    // Allow the module to perform install tasks.
    module_invoke($module, 'install');
    // Record the fact that it was installed.
    $modules_installed[] = $module;
    watchdog('system', '%module module installed.', array('%module' => $module), WATCHDOG_INFO);
  }
  ```

Keep in mind Drupal will install/enable the first module it finds matching the name; it doesn't mean it will be the module in that folder.

If then you need to be sure the modules in that folder are already downloaded, and you are creating a new site, I would rather create an installation profile, which allows you to declare its dependencies with a Drush Make file, and use it to create the new site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `modulename_install()` and then [module_enable()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7)

It may be usefull to check enabled modules with [module_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_list/7)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for installation profiles and distributions. From the [info page](https://www.drupal.org/developing/distributions):

> Installation profiles combine core Drupal, contributed modules, themes, and pre-defined configuration into one download. Installation profiles provide specific site features and functions for a specific purpose or type of site. They make it possible to quickly set up a complex, use-specific site in fewer steps than if installing and configuring elements individually.